# $\dim \ker (T\circ S) \ge \dim \ker T$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose we have two transformations $T\colon V\to W$ and $S\colon W\to V$ where $W,V$ are finite dimensional vector spaces.
And also suppose that $\ker T \subset \operatorname{Im}~S$ then is it true that $\dim \ker T \le \dim \ker (T\circ S)$?.

I thought this to be true but I don't see how to prove it.
Let $v\in \ker T$ then I want to show that $v\in \ker (T\circ S)$ which is sufficient to prove this claim.
So we have $w\in W$ s.t $v=Sw$ and $w\in \ker (T\circ S)$, but I want show that $v\in \ker (T\circ S)$.

So I guess this claim is false, but how to find a counterexample, I am clueless with this question, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Note that you will not be able to show that $v\in \ker T\circ S$. Indeed, $\ker T\circ S \subseteq W$ not in $V$ within which $v$ resides.

Comment: Sorry I fixed this typo I mean $S:W\to V$, I edited my post.

Comment: Yes, even with this edit note that $\ker T\circ S\subseteq W$ whereas $\ker T\subseteq V$ so you won't be able to show the inclusion you wished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\dim\ker T\circ S=\dim W-\dim TS(W)\ge\dim W-\dim T(V)=\dim\ker T$

Comment: So you don't need the extra condition of $ker T \subset Im S$, correct?

Comment: No. In fact, if $\ker T\subset Im S$ then $\ker TS=\ker T$. That is, this would be the least favorable condition.